# read only file system error on boot up after virtual box error

Tags: server, rsync

I have an ubuntu server.  Earlier this week I noticed I couldn't ssh in to the server remotely.  So I connected directly to the server, but I couldn't get prompt to come up it just continued to scroll messages to the screen.  I tried ctrl+c repeatedly but no luck.  So I did a hard reboot and got a virtual box error with a intriamsu prompt.  I tried reboot again and this time got to the "advanced" boot up option.  From there I was able to select "drop in to root terminal."  From root terminal I tried running rsync to recover from a back up of the operating system I had made a few days ago.  It copied most the files but mentioned it could rsync copy a few files back to the "/" directory.  I rebooted and now I'm getting a "Read-only file system: '/var/log/landscape/sysinfo.log' message.

I got a similar  "Read-only file system" message on reboot a couple months ago and I had to boot from live media and then run something like "fsck" if I remember right to fix it.

Does anyone have an idea what the issue might be and suggest how to fix it?  Since I can get to root terminal this time from the advanced boot option, do you think I'll still need to use live media to fix it, or can I just run a command from root?

also ideally I'd like to fix this just by running something like rsync from the daily back ups of the operating system I'm creating.  So I'm wondering why the command below didn't work.

original backup script

```
sudo rsync --exclude={mnt,/home} -avz / /mnt/data/storage1_1tb/backup_beavis_os/2023-11-09/
```

script I ran trying to restore from backup

```
rsync -avz /mnt/data/storage1_1tb/backup_beavis_os/2023-11-09/ /
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran `fsck -y /` from the "drop in to root terminal" option, then rebooted.  that fixed the readonly issue.  still not sure why doing the rsync from my back up didn't fix anything.